# Program displaying wrong values, what needs to be changed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

My program to display employee records works fine other than the face that it displays incorrect values when it comes to pay. What needs to be changed?

```
Sub AddPlist(month As String, age As String, employeenumberid As Integer, hourlyrateline As Integer)

        Dim hoursworkedline As String
        Dim normalhoursworked As Integer
        Dim overtimerate As String
        Dim normalpay As Decimal
        Dim overtimepay As Decimal
        Dim overtimehoursworked As Integer
        Dim grosspay As Decimal
        Dim taxrate As Decimal
        Dim taxdeducted As Decimal
        Dim nideducted As Decimal
        Dim netpay As Decimal

        Do
            Console.Write("Please enter hoursworked: ")
            hoursworkedline = Console.ReadLine()
            If Not hoursworkedline IsNot Nothing OrElse Not IsNumeric(hoursworkedline) Then Console.Write("hoursworked must be entered!!: ")
        Loop While Not hoursworkedline IsNot Nothing OrElse Not IsNumeric(hoursworkedline)

        If hoursworkedline > 40 Then
            normalhoursworked = 40
            overtimerate = hourlyrateline * 0.15
            overtimehoursworked = hoursworkedline - 40
            normalpay = normalhoursworked * hourlyrateline
            overtimepay = overtimehoursworked * overtimerate
            grosspay = normalpay + overtimepay
            taxrate = If(age < 18, 18, If(age < 60, 25, If(age > 60, 20, Nothing)))
            taxdeducted = grosspay * taxrate
            nideducted = grosspay * ((grosspay / 100) * 7)
            netpay = grosspay - taxdeducted - nideducted
        Else
            normalhoursworked = hoursworkedline
            overtimerate = hourlyrateline * 0.15
            overtimehoursworked = 0
            normalpay = normalhoursworked * hourlyrateline
            overtimepay = 0
            grosspay = normalpay + overtimepay
            taxrate = If(age < 18, 18, If(age < 60, 25, If(age > 60, 20, Nothing)))
            taxdeducted = grosspay * taxrate
            nideducted = grosspay * ((grosspay / 100) * 7)
            netpay = grosspay - taxdeducted - nideducted
        End If
```

Comment: What is your input, output and expected result? Did you also try to debug your program to find any problem? Only dumping code and saying "it doesn't work properly" is not the way to go...

Comment: normalhours = up to 40

Comment: Still doesn't answer any of the 2 questions I asked before. What is the input, what output do you get and what should be the desired result...

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger.  Examine the values of each variable at each step of the program.  Compare those values to the expected values.  Find out where the anomaly is.  `You have all the tools you need to figure this out.`

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed wrong is you're only paying 15% of the hourly rate for overtime.  I think you mean to multiply by 1.5 not .15

Plus you have a lot of duplication in your code consider this:

```
If hoursworkedline > 40 Then
    normalhoursworked = 40
    overtimehoursworked = hoursworkedline - 40
Else
    normalhoursworked = hoursworkedline
    overtimehoursworked = 0
End If
    overtimerate = hourlyrateline * 1.5
    normalpay = normalhoursworked * hourlyrateline
    overtimepay = overtimehoursworked * overtimerate
    grosspay = normalpay + overtimepay
 'Also your taxrate algorithm doesn't allow for someone exactly 60
    taxrate = If(age < 18, 18, If(age < 60, 25, If(age >= 60, 20, Nothing)))
 'Another thing your multiplying the grosspay by whole numbers not percentages
    taxdeducted = grosspay * (taxrate / 100)
 'Not sure what outcome you expect from this but it doesn't look quite right
    nideducted = grosspay * ((grosspay / 100) * 7)
    netpay = grosspay - taxdeducted - nideducted
```